# If $u,v\in V$ then there is a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ such that $T(u)=v$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space, not necessarily finite dimensional. If $u,v\in V$, is there a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ such that $T(u)=v$.

I proved the result for the finite dimensional case where I used a basis for $V$. What should one do for the infinite dimensional case?

Comment: You also have a basis in the infinite dimensional case if you accept AC

Comment: Is there a proof of this result without using a basis?

Comment: This is equivalent to saying that there is a linear functional $f\in L(V,\mathbb R)$ such that $f(u)=1$. Indeed, in this case you can take $T(x)=f(x)v$.

Comment: So we want to prove that for every $u\in V\setminus\{0\}$ there is $f\in L(V,\mathbb R)$ such that $f(u)\neq 0$.

Comment: Well, assuming the base field is $\mathbb R$, otherwise take the appropriate one.

Comment: The base field is any field.

Comment: Well then you would want $f\in L(V,K)$

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't even know if it is possible to prove that $L(V,K)\neq\{0\}$ without AC.

Comment: That is, there is always a non-trivial linear functional, without requiring anything on where it doesn't vanish

Answer (score -1):

Not always. If $u=0$, then $v$ must be $0$.

If $u\ne0$ and $V$ has an inner product, then $\displaystyle T(x)=\dfrac{\langle x,u\rangle}{\langle u,u\rangle}v$ works.

Geometrically, $T$ projects $V$ onto the subspace generated by $u$, which is canonically isomorphic to the subspace generated by $v$.

Comment: I like that you used inner products. But for a general vector space of infinite dimension, is there a way to prove the result without resorting to Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: This construction fails even in non-Hilbertian Banach spaces that we do know have a basis even without assuming AC, for instance $\ell^1$.